# Why is the vertical scroll bar attached to HTML when overflow: scroll is assigned to body?

Tags: html, css

If you run the following code, you will see that the vertical scrollbar gets attached to html and not body, which i expect.
I expect that because body has height defined as 800px but div.a has height of 1500px. So with overflow: scroll on body, scrollbar should appear on body and not html.
Can anybody shed some light on this ?

```css
html {
  background: black;
  margin: 20px;
}

body {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.a {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.b {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just want to understand the mechanics, it's due to something called propagation, which you can read about in the spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html If you want to understand the reasoning behind the mechanics, it has to do with html being a box in its own right, but body being the "host" of the layout content so to speak, and where generally most people apply page styles to. Someone else will elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this to work by telling the html to not show the overflow. Passing the burden over to its child to deal with.

```css
    * {
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
        background: black;
        margin: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 200px;
        background: red;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .a {
        width: 300px;
        height: 1500px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: yellow;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .b {
        width: 200px;
        height: 3000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="a">
        <div class="b">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my question was not "how to achieve this", it was "why this is happening".

Comment: It’s just simply the page was scrolling rendering the other scroll useless. If you’re ever struggling to get something to do what you want such as height 100%, you need to look at how the parent is set up. Cheers, Jason